# Transform Loading HOC to use Hooks and avoid react navigation problem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, high-order-component

I have made a HOC for showing a loading modal when my component is loading.

```
export const withLoading = (Component) => {
    return function HOCLoading(props) {
        const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
        return (
            <>
                <Component
                    {...props}
                    isLoading={isLoading}
                    setIsLoading={setIsLoading}
                />
                <Loading isLoading={isLoading} />
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

And I'm using it as

```
export default withLoading(MyComponent)
```

It was working fine until I realize that the `navigationOptions` stopped working, which is obvious because `withLoading` return a component that don't have `navigationOptions`, so my workaround was.

```
const LoadingMyComponent = withLoading(MyComponent)
```

And then set `navigationOptions` to `LoadingMyComponent`.

But this looks bad and doesn't make it easier than having a state for loading and rendering `Loading`.

Is there a way to transform this HOC into a react hooks or do something that I don't mess with the `navigationOptions` and also encapsulates the `Loading` component and logic?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem with `react-navigation` and I'm pretty sure that no really clean solutions exist, as the concept of setting a `navigationOptions` *static* property isn't, in the first place, really good (they should have made a hook for that in my opinion).

So either you copy `navigationOptions` (what you're doing), or, if this is not too problematic with your current architecture, you put everything in a `MyScreen` component that isn't wrapped by another HOC, like this:

```
const LoadingMyComponent = withLoading(MyComponent);

function MyScreen() {
  // You can exchange data with props or contexts if needed
  return <LoadingMyComponent />;
}

MyScreen.navigationOptions = { /* ... */ };

// MyScreen is never wrapped in a HOC and its navigationOptions are accessible
```